# SQL count consecutive rows

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I have the following data in a table:

```
|event_id    |starttime        |person_id|attended|
|------------|-----------------|---------|--------|
| 11512997-1 | 01-SEP-16 08:00 | 10001   | N      |
| 11512997-2 | 01-SEP-16 10:00 | 10001   | N      |
| 11512997-3 | 01-SEP-16 12:00 | 10001   | N      |
| 11512997-4 | 01-SEP-16 14:00 | 10001   | N      |
| 11512997-5 | 01-SEP-16 16:00 | 10001   | N      |
| 11512997-6 | 01-SEP-16 18:00 | 10001   | Y      |
| 11512997-7 | 02-SEP-16 08:00 | 10001   | N      |
| 11512997-1 | 01-SEP-16 08:00 | 10002   | N      |
| 11512997-2 | 01-SEP-16 10:00 | 10002   | N      |
| 11512997-3 | 01-SEP-16 12:00 | 10002   | N      |
| 11512997-4 | 01-SEP-16 14:00 | 10002   | Y      |
| 11512997-5 | 01-SEP-16 16:00 | 10002   | N      |
| 11512997-6 | 01-SEP-16 18:00 | 10002   | Y      |
| 11512997-7 | 02-SEP-16 08:00 | 10002   | Y      |
```

I want to produce the following results, where the maximum number of consecutive occurences where atended = 'N' is returned:

```
|person_id|consec_missed_max|
| 1001    | 5               |
| 1002    | 3               |
```

How could this be done in Oracle (or ANSI) SQL? Thanks!

Edit:

So far I have tried:

```
WITH t1 AS
(SELECT t.person_id,
    row_number() over(PARTITION BY t.person_id ORDER BY t.starttime) AS idx
    FROM the_table t
    WHERE t.attended = 'N'),
t2 AS
(SELECT person_id, MAX(idx) max_idx FROM t1 GROUP BY person_id)
SELECT t1.person_id, COUNT(1) ct
    FROM t1
    JOIN t2
    ON t1.person_id = t2.person_id
GROUP BY t1.person_id;
```

Comment: Just added what I have tried so far, when it comes to using analytical functions I'm still not entirely sure how to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main work is in the factored subquery "prep". You seem to be somewhat familiar with analytic function, but that is not enough. This solution uses the so-called "tabibitosan" method to create groups of consecutive rows with the same characteristic in one or more dimensions; in this case, you want to group consecutive N rows with a different group for each sequence. This is done with a difference of two ROW_NUMBER() calls - one partitioned by person only, and the other by person and attended. Google "tabibitosan" to read more about the idea if needed.

```
with
     inputs ( event_id, starttime, person_id, attended ) as (
        select '11512997-1', to_date('01-SEP-16 08:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10001, 'N' from dual union all
        select '11512997-2', to_date('01-SEP-16 10:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10001, 'N' from dual union all     
        select '11512997-3', to_date('01-SEP-16 12:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10001, 'N' from dual union all
        select '11512997-4', to_date('01-SEP-16 14:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10001, 'N' from dual union all
        select '11512997-5', to_date('01-SEP-16 16:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10001, 'N' from dual union all
        select '11512997-6', to_date('01-SEP-16 18:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10001, 'Y' from dual union all
        select '11512997-7', to_date('02-SEP-16 08:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10001, 'N' from dual union all
        select '11512997-1', to_date('01-SEP-16 08:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10002, 'N' from dual union all
        select '11512997-2', to_date('01-SEP-16 10:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10002, 'N' from dual union all
        select '11512997-3', to_date('01-SEP-16 12:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10002, 'N' from dual union all
        select '11512997-4', to_date('01-SEP-16 14:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10002, 'Y' from dual union all
        select '11512997-5', to_date('01-SEP-16 16:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10002, 'N' from dual union all
        select '11512997-6', to_date('01-SEP-16 18:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10002, 'Y' from dual union all
        select '11512997-7', to_date('02-SEP-16 08:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10002, 'Y' from dual
      ),
      prep ( starttime, person_id, attended, gp ) as (
        select starttime, person_id, attended,
               row_number() over (partition by person_id order by starttime) -
                   row_number() over (partition by person_id, attended 
                                      order by starttime)
        from   inputs
      ),
      counts ( person_id, consecutive_absences ) as (
        select person_id, count(*)
        from   prep
        where  attended = 'N'
        group by person_id, gp
     )
select person_id, max(consecutive_absences) as max_consecutive_absences
from   counts
group by person_id
order by person_id;
```

OUTPUT:

```
 PERSON_ID                MAX_CONSECUTIVE_ABSENCES
---------- ---------------------------------------
     10001                                       5
     10002                                       3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Oracle 12c` you could use [`MATCH_RECOGNIZE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm#DWHSG8956):

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE data AS 
SELECT *
FROM (
with inputs ( event_id, starttime, person_id, attended ) as (
  select '11512997-1', to_date('01-SEP-16 08:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10001, 'N' from dual union all
  select '11512997-2', to_date('01-SEP-16 10:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10001, 'N' from dual union all     
  select '11512997-3', to_date('01-SEP-16 12:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10001, 'N' from dual union all
  select '11512997-4', to_date('01-SEP-16 14:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10001, 'N' from dual union all
  select '11512997-5', to_date('01-SEP-16 16:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10001, 'N' from dual union all
  select '11512997-6', to_date('01-SEP-16 18:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10001, 'Y' from dual union all
  select '11512997-7', to_date('02-SEP-16 08:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10001, 'N' from dual union all
  select '11512997-1', to_date('01-SEP-16 08:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10002, 'N' from dual union all
  select '11512997-2', to_date('01-SEP-16 10:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10002, 'N' from dual union all
  select '11512997-3', to_date('01-SEP-16 12:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10002, 'N' from dual union all
  select '11512997-4', to_date('01-SEP-16 14:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10002, 'Y' from dual union all
  select '11512997-5', to_date('01-SEP-16 16:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10002, 'N' from dual union all
  select '11512997-6', to_date('01-SEP-16 18:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10002, 'Y' from dual union all
  select '11512997-7', to_date('02-SEP-16 08:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 10002, 'Y' from dual
      )
SELECT * FROM inputs
);
```

And query:

```
SELECT PERSON_ID, MAX(LEN) AS MAX_ABSENCES_IN_ROW
FROM data
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
   PARTITION BY PERSON_ID
   ORDER BY STARTTIME
   MEASURES FINAL COUNT(*) AS len
   ALL ROWS PER MATCH
   PATTERN(a b*)
   DEFINE b AS attended = a.attended
)
WHERE attended = 'N'
GROUP BY PERSON_ID;
```

Output:

```
"PERSON_ID","MAX_ABSENCES_IN_ROW"
10001,5
10002,3
```

**EDIT:**

As @mathguy pointed it could be rewritten as:

```
SELECT PERSON_ID, MAX(LEN) AS MAX_ABSENCES_IN_ROW
FROM data
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
   PARTITION BY PERSON_ID
   ORDER BY STARTTIME
   MEASURES COUNT(*) AS len
   PATTERN(a+)
   DEFINE a AS attended = 'N'
)
GROUP BY PERSON_ID;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ae82904c070cfded55a423d42c010ce8)**

Comment: Too convoluted. You don't need `ALL ROWS PER MATCH`. Each match should just return the `COUNT` for that match. Then, there should be no `WHERE` clause. Instead, the `PATTERN` should be `a+`, and the `DEFINE` clause should be `DEFINE a AS attended = 'N'`. This will be a more efficient solution (as shown by comparing plans).

Comment: I edited to delete the word `FINAL` in front of `COUNT(*)`. When you return `all rows per match`, `count()` behaves like an analytic function unless you qualify it with `final`. But when you return **one** row per match (the default), there is no "running" vs. "final". It is actually odd that Oracle doesn't throw a syntax error when you use `final (something)` with `one row per count`; it doesn't, but `final` is out of place there.